# I am try to get a "config.xml" working in my Phonegap App but getting "malformed config.xml"

Tags: cordova, navigation, malformed

It was wroking before i tryed to put in rim:navigation,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.0.0">


<name>---</name>
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="true" />
 <rim:navigation mode="focus"/>
 <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>

<icon src="icon.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
<description>
A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>

<author href="https://example.com" email="you@example.com">
S---- Y----
</author>
</widget>
```

Note: the dash are to hide personal information
If anyone know what wrong please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have no namespace defined for rim in the xml, that's why you're getting a malformed XML error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:rim = "http://????"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.0.0">
```

I don't know what URL the rim namespace should be defined against, but I'm guessing it will be mentioned in the phonegap documentation.